# VSTS - publish a web application and copy files over SSH

Tags: ssh, build, azure-devops, publish, artifact

I have a build process on VSTS which builds the web solution .sln file and publishes the artifact. All seems to be working fine.

Now I wish to use the artifact in a release to 'Publish' the web application and copy the published files over to a windows VM via SSH.

How can I get VSTS to 'publish' the application like it publishes in Visual Studio, or can I use the build Visual studio to publish.

.Net Framework Application.

[Image - Build process in VSTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igL9x.png)

Comment: What's the result after trying it with Copy Files Over SSH task?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use SSH you can in your Release pipeline you can use the "[Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=vsts)" Task:
[image]

If you do not have to use SSH you can use the "[Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts)" task:

[image]

These tasks will copy the build artifact to your windows VM.